# Object Browser inside the Android Studio

Tags: class, object, browser, android-studio, hierarchy

I need to navigate through the whole android api objects **inside the Android Studio** to find out classes that extend an individual class and also list of class and interfaces that is extended by an individual class in a hierarchy form.

In a simple word I need something like visual studio's Object Browser inside the android studio.

any solution?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

**Navigate** menu > **Type Hierarchy**.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, also regard to your answer I found that simply putting the cursor on desired class and pressing the **Ctrl + H** the same window will be opened, where you can select _Class_ Hierarchy, _Supertypes_ Hierarchy, _Subtypes_ Hierarchy from the top menu.

Comment: My god this is insanely helpful

Comment: Not sure if I don't know how to use this Type Hierarchy but this is not like ***Object Browser*** in Visual Studio at all, you can navigate all classes and components of some assembly using ***Object Browser*** but this `Type Hierarchy` is not something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what comes with the IDE: into Project Tab, select Project View, and browse the External Libraries.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Updating info since the question is from '13

Sadly I couldn't find anything after about an hour of digging beyond the 2 awkward and not comparable answers above.

My solution was to create a chrome window app of the page located at:
https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html

It's only after you leave Visual Studio that you understand why people say VS users are spoiled. I guess Balmer really meant it when he said it - DEVELOPERS DEVELOPERS DEVELOPERS DEVELOPERS =)